# Is there any ways to get around preprocessor macros?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <limits>

void main() {
    float x = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
}
```

This doesn't work due to the windows header having a max macro.

Is there a way to get around it without undefining the macro? Like some alternative way to call or some syntax candy for just that one instance?